# Make a SQL Server listener

Tags: android, sql-server, listener

I just finish develop some app that using firebase.
In firebase u can make a listener that listen when some data in some table get change.
I wondering if there some listener that make the same action but in Sql Server table?
Meaning - if some data,- get in, or remove, or just change -in specific table 
some some event will happen and the android program will know to start some function.
thanks
roey

Comment: `Meaning - if some data,- get in, or remove, or just change -in specific table some some event will happen `Search  for triggers